# Are sticky sessions needed when load-balancing Plone 3.3.5?

Tags: apache, load-balancing, plone

We encountered an issue which we suspect is a related to load balancing. We are having a 4 ZEO front-end clients behind Apache. Sometimes (from a logs) creation of a new content item logs an error.

```
2011-04-13T15:39:57 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1302701997.20.258830910503 https://x/intranet 
/portal_factory/MyType/xxx.2011-04-13.9797548037/xxx_edit
ValueError: Unable to find
```

What we suspect is happening is that portal_factory stores temporarily created items in the ZEO client session storage (how we can confirm this) and this storage is not shared between ZEO clients. When the user hits save, validation error happens and the browser is directed back to the edit screen. Then this edit screen view goes to another ZEO client which does not have the temporary "item in creation" in its session storage.

However, we have been running many load balanced Plone sites before and we haven't had reports of this issue before, so I suspect the error cause could be something else or there is a certain factor on this site triggering the behavior.

Here is some related information which is, unfortunately, very vague:

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/sticky-sessions-and-mod_proxy_balancer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Plone 3 there is still some code left in the object creation logic which does indeed use sessions. It's there to support a widget-like interface, where object creation is spread across multiple actual requests. This support and the code is gone in Plone 4.

This code in Plone 3 relies on accessing request.SESSION. The tricky bit is, that the code only uses the session if some other code already created it. No code in Plone (even Plone 3) should create the session in the first place, so usually it won't be there and won't be used. But if any code in the site does create the session, the object creation logic will use it as well. This should explain why you don't see the problem in most sites.

All of this is especially tricky, since simply calling request.SESSION will create a session. The content_edit_impl.py script in Products.Archetypes therefor uses a different API to get to the session:

```
# Avoid implicitly creating a session if one doesn't exists
session = None
sdm = getToolByName(context, 'session_data_manager', None)
if sdm is not None:
    session = sdm.getSessionData(create=0)
```

The *create=0* tells the API to avoid implicitly creating a session if none exists yet.

You can either try to find the code that creates the session, customize the code from Archetypes to remove the session part or move the session store into ZEO and share it across all Zope instances. While this isn't recommended for high traffic sites, it should work fine for simple scenarios (some hints at https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/wiki/TemporaryStorageInZeo).

Answer (score 1):

Your diagnosis is incorrect; the portal_factory tool is stateless and thus does not require any session affinity.

Your error message is also very vague and looks incomplete. Have you checked the instance log for complete tracebacks?